# Typecasting in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am trying to parse an yaml file in Groovy. However I am facing issue while typecasting the result to Map object.

Here is my logic

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import java.util.Map        
Reader reader = null 
int tokenCount = 0
def Map map = null 
StringTokenizer st = new java.util.StringTokenizer("Country.State.City", ".") 
reader = new FileReader("filepath") 
String val = null 
Yaml yaml = new Yaml() 
map = (Map) yaml.load(reader) 
tokenCount = st.countTokens() 
for (i=1;  i < tokenCount;  i++) {
  String token = st.nextToken() 
  map = (Map) map.get(token)
}
val = map.get(st.nextToken()).toString()
```

However I am getting error at line:
`map = (Map) map.get(token)` 
where it says:

```
"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'some value' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Map' error at line: 15"..
```

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: I suggest You to post the file You're trying to parse along with script ready to try.

Comment: Here is the groovy script https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fvwte5137znmb0/GScript.gsh?dl=0. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: the yaml file itself would be nice too.  from the error it could mean, that you are just accessing some "dead end" in your yaml.

Comment: using a dummy yaml file like `Header:
        Code:
                End: 'This is the end'` does work.

Comment: No, it does not look to be a dead end. I am able to print the string map.get(token). It only gets failed when I try to type cast it to Map. Link to sample yaml file https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f3gbrmafvl7lv7/cardconfig.yml?dl=0. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your provided yaml file is syntactically incorrect.  This is a fixed version:

```
location: C:\\Users\\amah11\\Desktop\\New folder
type: hi
Header:
    Code:
        Start: 0
        End: 2
        value: H00
    Owner:
        Start: 3
        End: 5
        value: AIM
    User:
        Start: 6
        End: 8
        Value: AIM
    number: 1
```

Note that `Code: **Static**` in the original messes things up.  And all the keys on the final level need a space after the `:` (e.g. `Start:3` is **wrong**).

The actual error message is:

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'Static Start:0 End:2 value:H00' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Map'
```

which is rather clear in showing, that there is something wrong with the original file.

You might want to consider using an editor, that detects errors like this right away.

An alternative to the original code, would be the use of inject on the tokenizer:

```
def map = new Yaml().load(new FileReader("cardconfig.yml"))
println new StringTokenizer('Header.Code.End', '.').inject(map) { r, s -> r.get(s) }
```

BTW: you don't need to import `java.util` in groovy.